# How to say just "Thanks" via mails in office environment?

Tags: communication, email

There were many situations I wanted to reply back saying just "Thanks"...

> Ex 01: Requesting a leave of absence and when getting a mail that it
>   is approved...
>
> Ex 02: Requesting a some file and when it was received....
>
> Ex 03: Requesting to do something and getting mail that it was done...

There are many times like that....

So I just want to say just thanks.

Then email is be like following.... **Last two line are signature.**

> Hi Name,
>
> Thanks.
>
> Thanks & Regards,
>
> My Name

Is this professional accepted mail? Or should I avoiding sending this types of mails? Then what should I add?

Comment: Generally, email programs allow you to change the signature on a per-message basis. Maybe when it's just a 'Thanks' email, remove the 'Thanks & Regards' line?

Comment: Whatever you do, please don't reply-all...

Comment: Why does your signature include Thanks and Regards?  Emails are not letters, they do not ever need salutations or a complimentary close. I would only include a statement like this is if was the norm at your company.  I can tell you that I never get emails form anyone with things like this in it, and I get emails from contractors, fellow employees and customers.

Comment: @HLGEM You mean, mentioning "Thanks & Regards" at end of the email isn't good or isn't professional?

Answer (score 1):

Yes, it's fine.

You may add a little extra to make it a little more friendly.

> Thanks, much appreciated

or

> Thanks, that helps a lot.

Try not to say thanks twice as you have done in your example above, it looks a little odd.

Answer (score 0):

That is fine, but a little "odd" presented. I have a automated **BR** (Best Regard) at the end of every mail I send. If I want to say thanks in that mail, I don't become to repetitive with having

> Thanks
>   Thanks & Regard.

Best Regard is friendly enough and you don't sound like a broken record, saying thanks all the time. :)